# How to set the color of missing/loading tiles in the Google Maps Javascript API?

Tags: google-maps

I made this little Cocoa app with a WebView that displays Google Maps in fullscreen. All nice and dandy but the tiles that are still being loaded are grayish which is very bright which is a pain on large displays. Is there any way to make them black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"), { backgroundColor: "#000000" });
```